# Replace value from one file to another

Tags: bash, awk, replace, grep, tags

Trying to figure out a way to replace a value from one file with the value of another using bash or awk or grep whichever is easiest.

Example:

File 1 - contains a list of all docker container images running on a node so:

docker/container-name:123456

docker/anothercontainer-differentname:7841216

File 2 - is a docker compose file in json format with a field named "image:" that contains values like this:

image: docker/container-name:latest

image: docker/anothercontainer-differentname:latest

What would be the best way to compare the two files and get the values from File 1 after the tag ":" for the matching name and replace that value in File 2 "latest" so that File 2 now shows

image: docker/container-name:123456

```
container-name:
  image: docker/container-name:latest
  ports:
    - 80
    - 50051
  mem_limit: 134217727
  cpu_shares: 100
  environment:
    SERVICE_NAME: container-name
    CONSUL_SERVER: consul.service.consul:8500/v1/kv/lde/
    SERVICE_80_CHECK_HTTP: "/health"
    SERVICE_50051_CHECK_TCP: "true"
  depends_on:
    - service-name
  network_mode: "bridge"
```

Comment: For modifying the docker compose json, I recommend  [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Comment: Can you provide an example of the docker compose file ?

Comment: @HakanBaba added

Comment: So it is actually in yaml. Are there multiple container descriptions in one docker-compose file ? In other words does it contain a list ? Or each docker compose file contains the yaml for one container-name.

Comment: @HakanBaba There is a list with multiple containers in a global compose file that is used to bring up all the containers in the environment, but the format is the same for each in the yaml file.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45679239/edit) and I'll retract my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have something that works on the yaml file. It is a little bit hacky I must say.

```
# Delimiter is optional white space around column
awk -F "[ \t\n]*:[ \t\n]*" '
# Pass on the first file. Save an array like a[containerName] = tag
NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next}
# For the second file only process lines that contain image
/image/ {
   # Image name contains a slash. Escape that (for sed)
   imgName=$2;
   sub(/\//,"\\\\/",imgName);
   #  print the command for the sed
   print  "s/image: "imgName":"$3"/image: "imgName":"a[$2]"/g"
} ' file1 file2  | \
# Call sed multiple times in place, modifying the input file.
xargs -I@   sed -i  '@' file2
```

In action:

```
$ cat file1
docker/container-name:123456
docker/anothercontainer-differentname:7841216
```

file 2 before

```
$ cat file2
container-name:
  image: docker/container-name:latest
container-name:
  image: docker/anothercontainer-differentname:latest
```

file 2 after

```
$ cat file2
container-name:
  image: docker/container-name:123456
container-name:
  image: docker/anothercontainer-differentname:7841216
```

Comment: @Ezekiel Watchman Let me know if this works for you. Depending on your container names, there may be some corner case that this fails.